# What does "fiend angelical" stand for?

Tags: meaning, literature

> Juliet--"Beautiful tyrant! fiend angelical!" (Act III Scene ii Line 77)

When Juliet refers to Romeo as a "beautiful tyrant," she is expressing an oxymoron because the acts of a tyrant will rarely be referred to as beautiful. What does "fiend angelical" stand for?

Comment: I haven't read Romeo and Juliet. However, their families or clans are enemies. So, they are not allowed to love each other. Maybe, Juliet expresses her conflictive feelings. To her, Romeo is supposed to be an enemy, however, she thinks him to be beautiful. My guess would be: angelical = angel-like.

Comment: _Fiend_ is another name for Satan as well as a noun that means _demon_. Demons live in Hell and angels live in Heaven, according to Judeo-Christian mythology, so as Marcus_33 says, it's another oxymoron.

Comment: While comments about it being an oxymoron are probably correct, it's worth noting that Satan's name is "Lucifer". The bible tell us that Lucifer - a / the angel of Light - highest of the angels, who sought to usurp Jehovah's position and was banished. So "fiend angelical" is an apt description of Satan - but probably not what Juliet (or Shakespeare) intended.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's another oxymoron. "Fiend" is a person of great malice or wickedness. "Angelical" means a person who is like an angel, i.e. very good.

Comment: *Angelical* can also mean a person of great beauty, making *fiend angelical* a synonym for *beautiful tyrant*.